# Join 2 arrays by key

Tags: php, arrays, join, merge

Suppose I have 2 arrays:

```
$arr1 = array (
        array (
                "animal" => "cat",
                "color" => "grey" 
        ),
        array (
                "animal" => "dog",
                "color" => "black" 
        ),
        array (
                "animal" => "mouse",
                "color" => "white" 
        ) 
);

$arr2 = array (
        array (
                "title" => "mouse",
                "name" => "Abby" 
        ),
        array (
                "title" => "dog",
                "name" => "Rex" 
        ),
        array (
                "title" => "dog",
                "name" => "Barney" 
        ),
        array (
                "title" => "mouse",
                "name" => "Georgie" 
        ) 
);
```

I now want to join them by key (`animal` from `$arr1` and `title` from `$arr2`) so that I have:

```
$arr1 = array (
        array (
                "animal" => "cat",
                "color" => "grey" 
        ),
        array (
                "animal" => "dog",
                "color" => "black",
                "name" => "Rex",
                "name" => "Barney" 
        ),
        array (
                "animal" => "mouse",
                "color" => "white",
                "name" => "Abby",
                "name" => "Georgie" 
        ) 
);
```

So just add the names of `dog` and `mouse` from `$arr2`.

My solution was:

```
foreach ( $arr1 as $key1 => $entry1 ) {
    foreach ( $arr2 as $key2 => $entry2 ) {
        if ($entry1 ["animal"] == $entry2 ["title"]) {
            $arr1 [$key1] ["name"] = $entry2 ["name"];
        }
    }
}
```

But it overwrites the first entry and so that I only get the last names:

```
$arr1 = array (
        array (
                "animal" => "cat",
                "color" => "grey" 
        ),
        array (
                "animal" => "dog",
                "color" => "black",
                "name" => "Barney"
        ),
        array (
                "animal" => "mouse",
                "color" => "white",
                "name" => "Georgie"
        ) 
);
```

I looked at [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), but it just merges the arrays without comparing their keys.

Comment: You can't use the same key more than once in a map. Halayem Anis' solution proposes to use an array behind the single "name" key and that's a good solution.

Comment: Simply update your code `$arr1 [$key1] ["name"][] = $entry2 ["name"];` as you can't have same key name

Comment: @Uchiha: Wow, that was easy!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So name index must be an array :)

try as follow

```
foreach ( $arr1 as $key1 => $entry1 ) {
    foreach ( $arr2 as $key2 => $entry2 ) {
        if ($entry1 ["animal"] == $entry2 ["title"]) {
            if (!isset($arr1[$key1]["name"])) {
                $arr1[$key1]["name"] = array();
            }
            $arr1 [$key1]["name"][] = $entry2 ["name"];
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$arr1 = array (
            array (
                    "animal" => "cat",
                    "color" => "grey" 
            ),
            array (
                    "animal" => "dog",
                    "color" => "black",
                    "name" => ["Rex", "Barney" ] 
            ),
            array (
                    "animal" => "mouse",
                    "color" => "white",
                    "name" => ["Abby", "Georgie"]
            ) 
);
```

Comment: Good solution, both for using an array and for using proper initialisation when the key isn't set yet.